# Why no implicit hyphenation for a single-word paragraph in this narrow minipage?

Tags: hyphenation

The following is a minimal example of a problem I'm having with hyphenation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\hyphenpenalty=0
\hyphenation{shame-less-ness}

\begin{minipage}{18mm}

  shamelessness

  shameless\-ness

  Four score and seven years ago, shamelessness our forefathers
  brought forth upon this continent a new nation.

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

It seems that for a single-word paragraph inside a narrow column, I can't convince LaTeX to hyphenate the word. The result when I typeset this document looks like this:

```
shamelessness
shameless-
ness
Four score
and seven
years ago,
shameless-
ness our
forefathers
brought
forth upon
this conti-
nent a new
nation.
```

The width of 18 mm is chosen to be narrower than the word "shamelessness." If I explicitly suggest a hyphenation, the word gets hyphenated. But implicit hyphenation doesn't happen, even though I did everything I could think of to encourage it, setting \hyphenpenalty to zero and explicitly providing a hyphenation for the word. However, when I insert the word at a random spot in a multi-line passage of text, it gets hyphenated.

Why is latex refusing to do the implicit hyphenation here, and what can I do to fix the problem?

[EDIT] Thanks, David Carlisle, for your comment. That answers my question.

Comment: tex doesn't hyphenate the first word (unless you use luatex) you can prefix with `\hspace*{0pt}` to allow hyphenation

Answer (score 5):

TeX doesn't hyphenate the first word (unless you use luatex) you can prefix with `\hspace*{0pt}` to allow hyphenation

Comment: Do you happen to know if this behavior is for typographical or technical reasons?

Comment: If it was _anyone_ else I'd say it was an out-by-one coding error, starting the scan at the wrong place. But great men get to define documented coding errors as features, so it's a feature. @gusbrs

Comment: @ DavidCarlisle :)

Comment: @gusbrs -- I can confirm that it's intentional.  I asked DEK and he said so.  (I ran into the problem in the early 1980s, creating a membership list with quite narrow columns, and encountering a very long city name in the geographic section.)  He pointed out a reason, but I've forgotten what it was

Comment: @barbarabeeton intentional or not, it's still wrong:-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks! Does your memory go as far as recalling if the reason was typographical or something else? (I'm just curious...).

Comment: @gusbrs -- I really don't remember, but I think it was mentioned that it doesn't happen very often.  (Maybe not in computer science.  Might be different if he were a chemist.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton  orifhewasgerman

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know how it is. :-) All good. Thanks again!